# OpenLayers 3 Navigation History Storing

Tags: openlayers

I am working on a navigation thing that show next/previous views. I am storing 
the map's current zoom, center and rotation to an array object. But I want manage that history and navigation in a efficient manner.And I don't want to use the browser's history.

Is there any default methods or functionalities in Openlayers 3 to provide the prev/next thing ?

Comment: something like this: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/permalink.html#map=2/1300149.41/5310539.22/0 move map and check browser location bar

Answer (score 1):

For my map I'm using [UndoManager](https://github.com/ArthurClemens/Javascript-Undo-Manager). You can store your state based on what you need but, after each navigation action you need to clear the vector and add the features you have stored in the state with before/after - depending on the situation.

This is how I store my state:

```
var addUndoRedo = function (type) {
        undoManager.add(new StateObject({
            vectorLayer: sourceVec,
            featuresBefore: featuresBefore, // this should be a cloned object of sourceVec.getFeatures() after draw/modify/remove
            featuresAfter: getFeatures(), // this should be a cloned object of sourceVec.getFeatures() at the time you call addUndoRedo()
            type: type // add,remove,modify,etc
        }));
    }
```

StateObject should be able to performUndo() and performRedo() which is basicall clearing the vector and replacing the with before/after data by case.

```
 // an example of case when you add a navigation level
 sourceVec.once("addfeature", function () {
            //extra code you need to run
            addUndoRedo('add');
        });
```

And this is how you undo/redo.

```
 if (undoManager.hasUndo()) {undoManager.undo();}
 if (undoManager.hasRedo()) {undoManager.redo();}
```

And if you need to reset for example you can always do :

```
undoManager.clear();
```